# Ambigous type variable

Tags: haskell, type-constraints

I wrote a little haskell program that just counts how many ones there are in a number (Int). When I try to execute it haskell complains about ambigous variable constraints.
I know that it comes from the use of floor. I also read some of the answers on stackoverflow. But I didn't really find a way around that.
Here's my code:

```
count_ones = count_ones' 0

count_ones' m 0 = m
count_ones' m n | n-10*n_new == 1 = count_ones' (m+1) n_new
                | otherwise         = count_ones' m n_new
                 where n_new = floor (n/10)
```

Any advice?

Comment: What's the exact error message? (And have you tried giving a type signature yourself?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
count_ones' m n | n-10*n_new == 0.1 = count_ones' (m+1) n_new
                | otherwise         = count_ones' m n_new
                 where n_new = floor (n/10)
```

In the first line, you compare `n - 10*n_new` to the fractional literal `0.1`, so the type of `n` and `n_new` must be a member of the `Fractional` class.

In the `where` clause, you bind `n_new = floor (n/10)`, so the type of `n_new` must be a member of the `Integral` class.

Since no standard type is a member of both classes (for good reasons), the compiler can't resolve the constraint

```
(Fractional a, Integral a) => a
```

when the function is called.

If you give type signatures to your functions, the compiler can often generate more helpful error messages.

The simplest fix for your problem is to change the binding of `n_new` to

```
n_new = fromIntegral (floor $ n/10)
```

Considering that in the comments you said that the `0.1` was a mistake and you should have used `1` instead, you probably want to use `Integral` types only and the closest transcription of your code would be

```
count_ones' :: Integral a => Int -> a -> Int
count_ones' m 0 = m
count_ones' m n
    | n - 10*n_new == 1 = count_ones' (m+1) n_new
    | otherwise         = count_ones' m n_new
      where
        n_new = n `div` 10
```

but it might be clearer to replace the condition `n - 10*n_new == 1` with `` n `mod` 10 == 1 ``.

However, that would require two divisions per step, which probably is less efficient. Using `divMod` should give you the quotient and remainder of the division with only one division instruction,

```
count_ones' m n = case n `divMod` 10 of
                    (q,1) -> count_ones' (m+1) q
                    (q,_) -> count_ones' m q
```

and if you can guarantee that you will only call the function with non-negative `n`, use `quot` and `rem` resp. `quotRem` instead of `div` and `mod` resp. `divMod`. The former functions use the results of the machine division instruction directly, while the latter need some post-processing to ensure that the result of `mod` is non-negative, so `quot` and friends are more efficient than `div` and company.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That was what I needed. Also I wanna hint a small misstake I did in the code above. The 0.1 must be a 1.

Comment: I wondered. Then it's more likely that you want the type to be an `Integral` type, and you should probably use some combination of `div, mod, quot, rem` rather than converting to a `Fractional` type for the division.

Comment: If you have the time for a short suggestion code. Please feel free to send it to me. I would appreciate it!

Comment: Updated the answer with example code and some useful suggestions regarding efficiency.